# is sklearn's predict_proba supposed to return straight lines?

Tags: scikit-learn, probability, predict

I need help understanding should predict_proba returning an array of straight lines ,each worth 1/arraylength. (Meaning - an even chance for all values, despite this being wrong.)

Predict_proba will return reasonable data if used on the same x that was fitted into the model. However, using any other x, even one that doesn't vary far will return straight lines. Is this an error? Do I not understand how it works?

For the record, I'm using SVC with rbf kernel. Data difference is only noise as it's simulated data.

Comment: Which classifier are you using?

Comment: What have you done to prevent overfitting?

Comment: How are the X values you use different from that of the training set? Do they have the same statistics?